# Change Date values using PL/SQL to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Have some dates in my local Oracle 11g database that are in this format:

```
01-JUL-85
```

How do I change it to this format (mm/dd/yyyy) using PL/SQL:

```
7/01/1985
```

With thanks...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the column is a date datatype then it is only your `NLS_DATE` settings that are causing them to be displayed in the format `DD-MON-YYYY`.

To check your current NLS_DATE format run the following:

```
SELECT value 
  FROM V$NLS_Parameters 
 WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Oracle stores all dates in an internal binary format and uses the NLS_DATE format to display them (unless explicitly told to display them differently).

You can either alter your `NLS_DATE` settings to `MM/DD/YYYY` or `TO_CHAR` the date column using:

```
TO_CHAR(<date_column>, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

to see the format you require.

You can alter the NLS_DATE format for your current session or alter the database parameters to change the default NLS_DATE format for the database itself.

If the column is a VARCHAR2 type then you'll need to convert to a date first and then you can format the output using either of the methods described above.

See: http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-nls.html

and: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format_sysdate.htm

e.g.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as current_date
  FROM dual;
```

or

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

SELECT sysdate
 FROM dual;
```

In pure PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
   v_date DATE := sysdate;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
END;
```